# How do I get started with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Are there any good resources to get started with AngularJs? Any good tutorials, blogs or books?

click for [official tutorial website](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial)

Comment: Anything particularly wrong with the provided link?

Answer (score 4):

Apart from offical tutorial you have mentioned  http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

you can refer the following sites

1. http://www.angularjstutorial.com/
2. http://www.thinkster.io/

3.http://tutorialzine.com/2013/08/learn-angularjs-5-examples/

you can also refer this book

Mastering Web Application Development with AngularJS [Import] [Paperback]
 you can buy this book from amazon site 
http://www.amazon.in/Mastering-Web-Application-Development-AngularJS/dp/1782161821

and also refer AngularJS from O'REILLY book and you can buy this book from the following link in amazon

http://www.amazon.in/AngularJS-Brad-Green/dp/1449344852

https://www.ng-book.com/

and some pdf for download

http://jan.varwig.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/AngularJS-Example.pdf

http://bcs.duapp.com/dreamlu/AngularJS%202013.pdf

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/07/30/angularjs-in-60-ish-minutes-the-ebook.aspx